# In C# running the PowerShell script first and then invoke Get-Process returns 0 result

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-3.0

in my c# code I have:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript(". ...\\WindowsPowerShell\\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1");
foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke())
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
}
ps.AddCommand("Get-Process");
ICollection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
Console.WriteLine(results.Count);
foreach (PSObject result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("---" + result.ToString());
}
```

If I run the Get-Process without running the script before hand (by commenting out the ps.AddScript part and the loop), the Get-Process do returns results; however the code that I provided will always return 0 for Get-Process.

Any idea why it is 0?

Comment: Looks like a delayed execution problem, but am not sure for that ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After each invoke, if we want to start a new command instead of passing a command into a pipeline from previous command, we should do a clear first:
    ps.Commands.Clear();

The complete code is:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript(". ...\\WindowsPowerShell\\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1");
foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke())
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
}
ps.Commands.Clear();
ps.AddCommand("Get-Process");
ICollection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
Console.WriteLine(results.Count);
foreach (PSObject result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("---" + result.ToString());
}
```

now the results.count displays correct row count and result.ToString() prints out the correct value.